# PHP OOP AJAX Form Submission Array Wont Append

Tags: php, arrays, ajax, forms, oop

I am trying to display the POST data of my form to the same page with Ajax. This is working fine but I am new to OOP and my class which builds an array with the POST content is getting overwritten on every request.

I understand I could post the data to a JSON file or Database but I wanted it to be solely displaying a "growing" array.

Index.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,500,600,700,800" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var frm = $('form');
            frm.submit(function (ev) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: frm.attr('method'),
                    url: frm.attr('action'),
                    data: frm.serialize(),
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("#response").html(data);
                    }
                });
                ev.preventDefault();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="flex40">
            <div class="container40">
                <form id="form" action="response.php" method="post">
                    <input name="postName" type="text" placeholder="Name" required>
                    <select name="postEyeColour">
                        <option>Blue</option>
                        <option>Red</option>
                        <option>Yellow</option>
                        <option>Green</option>
                    </select>
                    <button name="submit" type="submit">New Person</button>
                </form>
                <div class="character-table">
                    <table id="response"></table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

response.php

```
<?php     
require_once 'Classes/Person.php';

$character = new Person;

if (isset($_POST['postName'])) {
    $character->createNewPerson();
    $character->getPersonList();
}    
?>
```

Classes/Person.php

```
<?php     
class Person {    
    private $personList = array();  

    public function createNewPerson() {    
        // Build Array From Post Data
        $newPerson= array(
            "Name" => $_POST['postName'],
            "Eye Colour" => $_POST['postEyeColour']
        );    
        //Push New Person to data array
        $this->personList[] = $newPerson;
    }

    public function getPersonList() {
        print_r($this->personList);
    }      
}    
?>
```

What happens is that the data is posted to the array but every time I add some more data it is resetting the Array with the new data not appending it.

Comment: You aren't persisting your data anywhere (a database, a file...) so everytime you call your php script you instantiate a new `Person`, so there's no way it would keep what you wrote on previous calls.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without actually saving the data somewhere? I was naively thinking that since I was using AJAX and not hitting the page directly it would hold onto the current instance and not instantiate a new Person? Thank you for your reply!

Comment: Data has to be saved somewhere, somehow. I mean, I can think of a couple of ways to do this without persisting stuff, but I'm not sure it would fit in a comment. For example writing your own http server in php and keeping the object alive between http calls.

Comment: Can I recommend that you pass the data into `createNewPerson()` as this will allow you to use it more freely.  At the moment it's hardwired to getting values from `$_POST` which is a bit restricting.

Comment: @ Nigel Ren - Could you explain what you mean by this? Pass the data through as arguments?

Comment: Yes - something like `public function createNewPerson( $name, $eyeColour)`